# Out of turn action

Tags: poker-strategy, raise, mtt

UTG is thinking.
UTG +1 raises out of turn for 5BBs. He apologies and takes his money back.

UTG, doesn't see that, UTG +1 had raised and he raises to 2.5BBs.

Questions:
1) Does UTG +1 can just call 2.5BBs, or does he have to put 5BBs. What are the options available for UTG +1, knowing UTG raised 2.5BBs.

2) What are the options for UTG to keep the 5BBs from UTG+1 in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I believe in this situation, UTG +1 has all the options that he/she would normally have. ignoring other players in the hand, UTG gets a nice advantage (if they paid attention) because they get a hint of what UTG +1 would have done if UTG would have folded. UTG +1 is basically only hurting himself/herself by raising out of turn. If any player had a big problem with it, (suspected angle shooting or repeatedly acting out of turn) then they could call over the floor and have them make a ruling which varies from place to place.

2) UTG here did not see the raise out of turn, but if UTG did see it the most that he/she could do is call over the floor or tournament director for a ruling.  I don't think that the floor would ever make them put the 5bb back out but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, when UTG+1 raises out of turn, he's committed to that raise *if there's no intervening action*, but UTG's raise takes him off the hook, and he can take any action he likes.

Comment: 2) Only way to ensure that the 5bb raise stays in play is for the UTG player to check. UTG+1 is forced to put his bet out if UTG checks.